How to save entities previous data for audit table using AOP in Spring boot
I created AuditAspect.class to log audit details for my entities when jpa execute  UPDATE and DELETE operations. When updating and deleting I expect to save previous data as a String value in my audit table. But it only saves new data. when I'm debugging, AuditAspect.class  beforeSave() method executes after Entity's Repository.save() methods executed.
AuditAspect.class
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuditAspect {

    private final AuditDetailsRepository auditRepository;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public AuditAspect(AuditDetailsRepository auditRepository, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.auditRepository = auditRepository;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(..)) && args(entity)")
    public void saveEntity(Object entity) {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.delete(..)) && args(entity)")
    public void deleteEntity(Object entity) {}

    @Before("saveEntity(entity)")
    public void beforeSave(Object entity) {
        if (isEntityManaged(entity) && shouldLogAudit(entity)) {
            Optional<Object> existingEntity = findExistingEntity(entity);
            if (existingEntity.isPresent()) {
                saveAudit("UPDATE", existingEntity.get(), entity);
            } else {
                saveAudit("CREATE", null, entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Before("deleteEntity(entity)")
    public void beforeDelete(Object entity) {
        if (shouldLogAudit(entity)) {
            saveAudit("DELETE", entity, null);
        }
    }

    private Optional<Object> findExistingEntity(Object entity) {
        try {
            Object entityId = getEntityId(entity);
            return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(entity.getClass(), entityId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to find existing entity", e);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private void saveAudit(String action, Object oldEntity, Object newEntity) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> oldData = oldEntity != null ? extractData(oldEntity) : null;
            Map<String, Object> newData = newEntity != null ? extractData(newEntity) : null;
            String oldDetails = oldData != null ? objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oldData) : null;
            String newDetails = newData != null ? objectMapper.writeValueAsString(newData) : null;

            AuditDetails auditDetails = AuditDetails.builder()
                    .action(action)
                    .oldDetails(oldDetails)
                    .details(newDetails)
                    .entityType(newEntity != null ? newEntity.getClass().getName() : oldEntity.getClass().getName())
                    .entityId(newEntity != null ? getEntityId(newEntity) : getEntityId(oldEntity))
                    .time(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();
            auditRepository.save(auditDetails);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save audit details", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEntityManaged(Object entity) {
        try {
            // Check if the entity has a primary key value to determine if it's an update
            return getEntityId(entity) != null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String getEntityId(Object entity) {
        try {
            return entity.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(entity).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get entity ID", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldLogAudit(Object entity) {
        // Implement logic to exclude certain entities from audit logging
        // For example, exclude entities of type AuditDetails themselves
        return !(entity instanceof AuditDetails);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> extractData(Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        if (entity == null) return data;

        for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToMany.class)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToOne.class) || field.isAnnotationPresent(OneToOne.class)) {
                Object associatedEntity = field.get(entity);
                if (associatedEntity != null) {
                    try {
                        Field associatedIdField = associatedEntity.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
                        associatedIdField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object associatedId = associatedIdField.get(associatedEntity);
                        data.put(field.getName() + "Id", associatedId != null ? associatedId.toString() : null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("extractData: Error extracting ID for associated entity", e);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Object value = field.get(entity);
                if (value != null) {
                    data.put(field.getName(), value);
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}

AuditDetails.class
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuditDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String action;
    private String details;
    private String oldDetails;
    private String entityType;
    private String entityId;
    private LocalDateTime time;
}

Example entity
Appointment.class
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Appointment extends MultiTenantManager {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private AppointmentStatus status;
   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Resource resource;

    

}

When I change the appointment Status "NEW" to "COMPLETED" its audit table values show this
in details column ===>
{"date":[2024,6,26],"resourceId":"22d8b3dc-aff6-4850-9b84-0e86d9de32f1","amount":2000.00,"customerId":"98d8df10-e5ed-4ac9-9cf9-103e6ac6ec39","appointmentNumber":2406101000,"createdDateTime":[2024,6,10,11,47,32,751741000],"startTime":[10,0],"id":"0032e432-ad7c-4c5d-aba8-c4e368b0bdfe","endTime":[12,0],"status":"COMPLETED","updatedDateTime":[2024,6,17,18,23,56,157188000]}
in old data column ==>{"date":[2024,6,26],"resourceId":"22d8b3dc-aff6-4850-9b84-0e86d9de32f1","amount":2000.00,"customerId":"98d8df10-e5ed-4ac9-9cf9-103e6ac6ec39","appointmentNumber":2406101000,"createdDateTime":[2024,6,10,11,47,32,751741000],"startTime":[10,0],"id":"0032e432-ad7c-4c5d-aba8-c4e368b0bdfe","endTime":[12,0],"status":"COMPLETED","updatedDateTime":[2024,6,17,18,23,56,157188000]}
As you can see,The same status values are shown in both(COMPLETED).But i need to get  old Status value for old data column (Which is NEW)
Can someone please look in to this and give me a solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance!!

Using AOP is a good approach to trigger events when updates or deletions occur in a JPA repository, but EntityListeners might be a more efficient way.
In EntityListener, updates and deletions are detected through methods annotated with @PreUpdate and @PreRemove.
Listener class
@Component
public class AuditEntityListener {

    private final AuditDetailsRepository auditRepository;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public AuditEntityListener(AuditDetailsRepository auditRepository) {
        this.auditRepository = auditRepository;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

    // Method to handle pre-update audit logging
    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Object entity) {
        Object oldEntity = entityManager.find(entity.getClass(),getEntityId(entity));
    saveAudit(oldEntity, "UPDATE");
}

    // Method to handle pre-remove audit logging
    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(Object entity) {
        saveAudit(entity, "DELETE");
    }

    private void saveAudit(Object entity, String action) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> oldData = extractData(entity);
            String oldDetails = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oldData);

            AuditDetails auditDetails = AuditDetails.builder()
                    .action(action)
                    .oldDetails(oldDetails)
                    .details(null) // New data can be set later
                    .entityType(entity.getClass().getName())
                    .entityId(getEntityId(entity))
                    .time(LocalDateTime.now())
                    .build();

            auditRepository.save(auditDetails);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save audit details", e);
        }
    }

    private String getEntityId(Object entity) {
        try {
            return entity.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(entity).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get entity ID", e);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Object> extractData(Object entity) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        if (entity == null) return data;

        for (Field field : entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToMany.class)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ManyToOne.class) || field.isAnnotationPresent(OneToOne.class)) {
                Object associatedEntity = field.get(entity);
                if (associatedEntity != null) {
                    try {
                        Field associatedIdField = associatedEntity.getClass().getDeclaredField("id");
                        associatedIdField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object associatedId = associatedIdField.get(associatedEntity);
                        data.put(field.getName() + "Id", associatedId != null ? associatedId.toString() : null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("extractData: Error extracting ID for associated entity", e);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Object value = field.get(entity);
                if (value != null) {
                    data.put(field.getName(), value);
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
}

Through @PreUpdate, I used entityManager to find the previous entity before the update, and then passed it to the saveAudit method.
And when you apply the @EntityListeners annotation to an Entity, the EntityListeners monitor the entity.
Entity
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EntityListeners(AuditEntityListener.class)
public class Appointment extends MultiTenantManager {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private AppointmentStatus status;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Resource resource;
}

have a nice day - kevin
